# Wordpress database is not updating

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So i have got an issue with Wordpress on my local machine i am running OSX 10.10.5

I am creating a Wordpress theme from the scratch and it seems to be an issue with the database. When i create a new post, it is not added to the database, next when i try to install a plugin, it is also not added to the database. I thought it is down to permissions, but no.

I have recently tried to install php mcrypt on my machine and was playing a lot with Apache/MySQL/PHP config files as well, maybe that affected as well?
I have completely removed mysql, still nothing.

I am running MAMP for local development so i thought it should be all good, but also no

Answer (score 0):

If you have been playing with things that can be causing the issue,  I think this will be very difficult to solve for you or any other, without knowing exactly what you have changed when the issue appear.

I recommend to just reinstall MAMP, WordPress and anything you have been playing around.

For self-experience, I recommend you to don't change things you don't know on a site that is a production site. Make a site for testing or at least, take a backup before. I have already learned that the hard way :)

Comment: Yea, I am backtracing what I have changed in settings, Its because I was installing an app that runs laravel on the backend and it to get it to work,migrate the db and etc i need php, apache and mcrypt to be working, so mamp was not an option, at least i have tried that. And at the end I didnt get it to work. If i trail mamp log file for errors it says that I cannont access to database root@localhost using password:yes. so i know it has some sort of issue to connect to db